# Couldn't connect to server for "http://mercure:7001/.well-known/mercure" // TransportException

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, push-notification, mercure

i'm little confused about this so i want your help
in my docker-compose i think i have configured all want it must be.
But the thing is when im trying publish somthing in mercure via symfony he dont want to do it
but when i try without passing via symfony(with js) it work
If some one has an idea it will be cool

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      target: Symfony_PHP
    container_name: web_symfony
    ports:
      - 90:90
      - 943:943
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./portailcse/:/var/www/app/
      - symfony-cache:/var/www/app/var/cache
      - symfony-log:/var/www/app/var/log
      - symfony-vendor:/var/www/app/vendor
    networks:
      - dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    container_name: mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      # Uncomment the following line to disable HTTPS
      SERVER_NAME: ':90'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: 'testjwt'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: 'testjwt'
      # PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '*'
      # CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '*'
      # ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 1
      # DEBUG: 'debug'
      # Uncomment the following line to enable the development mode
    command: /usr/bin/caddy run -config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    ports:
      - 7001:90
    volumes:
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    networks:
      - dev
  
networks:
  dev:
volumes:
  symfony-vendor:
  symfony-log:
  symfony-cache:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0i7a.png)

```
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
# See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html#configuration
# The URL of the Mercure hub, used by the app to publish updates (can be a local URL)
MERCURE_URL=http://mercure:7001/.well-known/mercure
# The public URL of the Mercure hub, used by the browser to connect
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://mercure:7001/.well-known/mercure
# The secret used to sign the JWTs
MERCURE_JWT_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InB1Ymxpc2giOlsiKiJdLCJzdWJzY3JpYmUiOlsiKiJdLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InJlbW90ZUFkZHIiOiIxMjcuMC4wLjEifX19.y6WSZvqaNkya67gRr2ta9R4fnPAv9-7EmPhQvfz6GJA
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```

thanks you all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp8Ay.png)

Comment: `mercure` is not resolvable outside docker, so you need to use the host ip to connect in `MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL` and the same for the internal one, you should use `90` as the port in `MERCURE_URL`.

Comment: Awesome thanks man 
i have added on .end.local
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET=testjwt
(is not normal. normally we use signed JWT but now we use secrete key...
thanks i will make it done ^^